# Broadleaf Community - SpEL error when using hibernate update instead of create

Tags: spring, hibernate, thymeleaf, spring-el, broadleaf-commerce

I am using the community demo site to get familiar with the Broadleaf offering. As a first step, we are trying to prevent the reloading of the database each server start. When I update the hibernate auto properties from 'create' to 'update'

```
blPU.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
blEventPU.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

the server will work (restart) a few times but eventually fail on start with the following error:

```
2018-11-08 08:51:46.226 ERROR 72159 --- [nio-8443-exec-8] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : 
[THYMELEAF][https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-8] Exception processing template "error": Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "'locale-' + session.blLocale.localeCode" (template: "error" - line 12, col 7)
```

If I re-run the server with 'create' set, the server will start normally, but we've now lost any data customization.

Any ideas on why the database would need to be 'refreshed' for SpEL to pick up on this locale property?

Comment: When does it fails? When you open a page? On when you are starting your server? From the looks of it, it looks like a Thymeleaf issue.

Comment: @AlainCruz it fails on server startup. The thymeleaf template fails to load due to spring not being able to resolve the session.blLocale.localeCode referenced. It seems odd that a session parameter would fail a server start and even weirder that rebuilding the db would make it work. Clearly I am missing something here.

Comment: This really sounds like it fails when you try to load a webpage _after_ the server has started up. This error is typically seen when there is an exception early in the web request processing (before BroadleafRequestProcessor), which causes an exception when rendering the error template. You should be able to remove `th:class="${'locale-' + session.blLocale.localeCode}"` from error.html and see the error page, which should give a clue to the underlying problem.
If this error is happening _during_ server start, please post more of the stack trace